# Launch controls on stopped applications

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Assuming that my application does not need a single `Activity` launch to be useful to the customer, what should i do overcome the `Intent.FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` launch controls behavior after a new installation starting from Android 3.1, which prevents my `BroadcastReceiver` to be invoked on `TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`?

It's all about [AutoMute on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andnexus.automute) and [Launch controls on stopped applications starting from Android 3.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols)

Comment: There's no way around the fact that your `BroadcastReceiver` will not work until your app has started an `Activity`.  If nothing else, you can show a "thanks for installing" screen.

Comment: That requires a new permission, right? :-(

Answer (score 0):

> what should i do overcome the Intent.FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES launch controls behavior after a new installation starting from Android 3.1, which prevents my BroadcastReceiver to be invoked on TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED?

Add a launcher activity. You need it for configuration, license agreements, support channels, etc. anyway.

Or, find something else that will use an explicit `Intent` to invoke one of your components.

> It's all about AutoMute on Google Play

According to the Play Store listing, it has an activity for configuration.

Comment: Yes, it has an Activity for configuration but it will not be started if you install the app from play store. You have to launch manually after you install the app.

Comment: @BenjaminLehejcek: Then you are as set as you are ever going to be, most likely. Again, you need something to use an explicit `Intent` to invoke one of your activities, services, or receivers. For the vast majority of apps, that's the launcher activity. Occasionally, there will be other scenarios, where you are more of a plugin to another app (e.g., Locale plugins) or to the system (e.g., input method editors, device admin apps), where there is some other explicit-`Intent`-based communications that suffice.

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible without launching configuration Activity once?

Comment: @BenjaminLehejcek: As I have said twice, and will repeat again in boldface for emphasis: **you need something to use an explicit `Intent` to invoke one of your activities, services, or receivers**. I don't know enough about your app to say whether there is anything other than a launcher activity that will fill this role. For most apps, the launcher activity is not merely the only option, but the best option, since they have one anyway.